# Is there a way to calculate if a domed cylinder will balance on its dome or is top-heavy?

Tags: gravity

I noticed that some domed cylinders have a centre of gravity low enough to balance on their dome, and others just topple over.

[image]
[image]

I'm sure you can predict this mathematically:

My question is: **Is there a way to calculate if a domed cylinder will balance on its dome or is top-heavy?**

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the location of the centre of mass with respect to the centre of curvature of the hemispherical dome. If the centre of mass is high (above the centre of curvature) balancing on the dome is unstable, low and it should be stable.

To show this look at small disturbances from the equilibrium configuration. In one case we have a moment leading to toppling and in the other to a moment in the direction back towards the equilibrium position. Or if you prefer in one case the disturbance leads to a reduction in potential energy and the other an increase.